# In edit mode Date is not populating in material-ui/DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, reactjs-flux

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
```

I am using DatePicker component

```
 this.state = {
      contractDate: ''
 }

<DatePicker
     hintText=""
     formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
     value={this.state.contractDate}
     onChange={this.handleContractDateChange}
  />
```

The onChange function looks like Below

```
handleContractDateChange = (event, date) => {
   this.setState({
          contractDate: date,
        });

      }
```

While creation i am selecting the date its working [image: On edit mode I am getting date Correctly but the value is not populating in the UI]

[On edit mode I am getting date Correctly(in console) but the value is not populating in the UI

Comment: Please guide me to populate date picker from state value

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, it is hard to tell what the issue might be.

Here is a working example that will hopefully help you find the issue:

[image: Edit xrk0pkx1z]

Comment: I am able to select date as similar but in edit mode i am  taking the same state value still the value is not populating

Comment: @user9883888 I am not sure I understand. Are you saying that when the page "loads" the value is not being populated? If that is the case, you need to set the value to state in the constructor or one of the other lifecycle functions. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: I am setting the value in constructor state when the page loads but still date is populating remainiing all fields are populating but date alone is not populating.